# What the Application Insights query represents

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-durable-functions

Assume I am sending 1 request per 10 minutes in Azure Durable Functions. Then, in the Applications Insights log, enter the following in the query

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(10m) 
| summarize avg(duration) by bin(timestamp, 1m)
| render scatterchart
```

In this case, **the "avg_duration" displayed in the result is the response time from the time one request is triggered to the time the result is returned?**

In the case of a picture,
Trigger -> client function -> ... -> client function -> return
Does this picture mean that this entire sequence took 3075ms?
Or is this time a fragment of the sequence?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the case of a picture, Trigger -> client function -> ... -> client function -> return Does this picture mean that this entire sequence took 3075ms? Or is this time a fragment of the sequence?

```
requests
| where name == "client_function"
| where timestamp > ago(10m)
| summarize avg(duration) by bin(timestamp, 1m)
| render scatterchart
```

Yes, it is providing the total time taken by the entire sequence to complete.

[image]

You can verify the same in ***Monitor*** blade of `client_function`.

[image]

You can also get the duration from logs using ***requests***.

[image]